# tornado multi-process HTTPServer()

Tags: tornado

I have a 4 core system and wanted to test the multi process tornado functionality. I start my program and it shows that 4 processes are started:

```
[I 151013 19:19:44 process:124] Starting 4 processes
```

My code is pretty much similar to what's listed in the documentation:

```
server = HTTPServer(app)
server.bind(8000)
server.start(0)  # Forks multiple sub-processes
IOLoop.current().start()
```

In my main handler I intentionally call a time.sleep(10) to block the process. I was under the impression that if I connect another client to the webserver with this client being blocked it will still be serviced because there's 4 processes listening on the port. And only until I reach > 4 processes of (assuming that they are all still blocking) will a client have to wait for a connection.

However when I tested this the second client has to wait for the first one to unblock. So I'm not sure I'm understanding the purpose of a multi process listening on the same port. Am I missing something? What's the purpose/ advantage of forking multi processes for the HTTPServer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're running into a surprising browser behavior that trips up many users when they first try Tornado, read the frequently-asked ["My code is asynchronous, but it’s not running in parallel in two browser tabs"](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/faq.html#my-code-is-asynchronous-but-it-s-not-running-in-parallel-in-two-browser-tabs).

> Browsers will recognize that you are trying to load the same page in two different tabs and delay the second request until the first has finished.

Comment: Ah yes i missed that part of the documentation. It works when i used different browsers. Cheers Jesse